# abrt-server sent an email to root@localhost, but there are no updates in var/mail/root

Tags: python, abrt, incron

I'm debugging an issue with python and incron, when I run my script, and then checking the status, it says it has an error. then it said it sent an email to root@localhost, I'm assuming this is at /var/mail/root? When I check that file though, the last update was 10 days ago. Now I'm not sure where I should look for the detailed error message

Comment: Don't assume. Check your mail logs. What do those say?

Comment: root mail logs doesn't say anything, last time it was updated was on july 21. anyway I've seen what I'm looking for the error details, they are at var/spool/abrt/Python... But it is still confusing that abrt is saying it sent an email to root@localhost but the mail logs don't say anything. Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: If your mail logs (note: mail *logs* -- typically in /var/log -- not mail *spool* -- typically in /var/mail or /var/spool/mail) don't say anything, then your mail system isn't running. If that's the case, then you should fix that before trying to figure out why you aren't getting mail. Your mail system not running may even be the entire reason why you aren't getting mail that you expect to get.

Comment: alright, thanks. I have mailx already setup, but I will review abrt config documentation